# What is best way of iterating over Dictionary with multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

**EDIT** I'm limited to the .Net version 2.0 so I don't believe I can use the Task Parallel Library in this case.

I've got a dictionary of objects.

I need to iterate over all of them and perform an expensive, but embarrassingly parallelizable ,  calculation on each element.

Currently I'm using a single thread to iterate over the entire dictionary.

Approach 1

> I've toyed with using a thread pool to split the calculations over
>   multiple threads but that leads to the question of how to pass this to
>   separate threads?

I currently convert the keys collection to an array and pass part of the array to separate threads so they can use the key to look up the value and perform the calculation.

Approach 2

> Alternatively I could iterate over each key and dispatch a thread in
>   a thread pool to each element.

The second approach is slower.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Are your calculations dependent on prior values in the dictionary?

Comment: @Paul, no they aren't, that's what I mean by the calcs being embarassingly parallel.

Comment: Any changes to the dictionary, from these calc threads or another thread would conflict with "embarrassingly parallel". Please clarify.

Comment: @Henk, I think we're going to disagree here.  Embarrassingly parallel only means the calcs can be done in parallel. It shouldn't have anything to do with writing to the map as long as those updates don't affect any other calcs:)  I hope that clarifies it for you!

Comment: No, you ask about iterating over a dictionary but you don't specify the usage of that dictionary. Makes it an icomplete question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(dictionary, keyValuePair => {...});
```

Comment: Great answer, I figured there was a simpler way than using a thread pool

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  I did a post on this a while back along with some performance numbers and a gotcha with locking variables to prevent issues.  http://tsells.wordpress.com/?s=parallel

Answer (score 6):

you can use this approach (.NET 4)

```
var elements = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

      Parallel.ForEach(elements, (element) =>
                {
                    // USE element the way you need it
                }
```

Comment: It shouldn't need a ConcurrentDictionary, the question implies read-only access.

Comment: @Henk what about the question implies read-only access?  I wrote it and just read it and I can't see anything implying read only access:)

Comment: It states "iterating over" and "embarrassingly parallel". That excludes simultaneous Adding to the Dict.

Comment: @Henk, embarrassing parallel doesn't mean no writing, it just means each calc is independent of others.  Iterating also doesn't preclude writing:) No worries, we agree to disagree:)  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @chollida, But another thread may write to dictionary and iterator will change and an exception will fire if you not use ConcurrentDictionary!